# Identify a late 90s game: keeping a floating carpet from being flooded

Tags: identify-this-game

I distinctly remember the carpet having a red and white checkerboard pattern.

The environment is just the sky, with the frequent rain: the objective is to prevent the carpet from being flooded by raising specific parts of it, forming puddles.

I was playing this game approximately 2 decades ago, on Windows XP. However, I'm pretty sure it originally came out for Windows 98.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Wetrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetrix) perhaps? It was a PC and Nintendo 64 title with a Tetris-esque element to the wall building.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Wetrix is indeed the one!

I should've probably mentioned I remembered the platform's skin changing as the game progresses, but I wasn't completely sure about it.

Comment: I get the impression that the goal is to create lakes, not to prevent the carpet being flooded. Otherwise you'd just create a big mountain in the centre, and all water would be easily evacuated.

Comment: Playable over at https://arcadespot.com/game/wetrix/